# compare position of multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a draggable object. When the objects left position is the same as another div, an alert message should appear.
Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9yyKN/1/

```
<div id="ha">1</div>
<div id="ha2" class="box">2</div>
<div id="ha3" class="box">3</div>
<div id="ha4" class="box">4</div>
```

The JS:

```
var posbox = $(".box").position();
var boxleft = posbox.left;
$("#ha").draggable({
drag: function () {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    var left = pos.left;
    if (left == boxleft) {
        alert("same");
    }
}
});
```

The problem is that it only compares the first div with the class box. The number of divs may change from time to time so i can't just put every position in a string and then compare the draggable to each of them. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this -

```
var posbox = $(".box").map(function () {
    return $(this).position().left;
}).get();
$("#ha").draggable({
    drag: function () {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        var left = pos.left;
        var p = $.inArray(left, posbox);
        if (p > -1) {
            console.log("same to : " + $('.box').eq(p).text());
        }
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/9yyKN/4/

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to iterate through all `div`s that have a class of `box` and store their `position().left` values in an array like so:

```
var arr = [];
$('.box').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).position().left);
});
```

Then, in your `drag` function, iterate over the array when dragging. Run this within your `if` statement.

```
$.each(arr, function(i) {
    if(left == arr[i]) {
        alert("same");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yyKN/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ha").draggable({
    drag: function () {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        var left = pos.left;
        $(".box").each(function() {
            if (left == $(this).position().left) {
                alert("same");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

this is not recommanded if `.box`s are not moving ... better is cache positions to array and then compare